# How to get facebook fan page ID

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I develop a facebook app. This app will be add to Page's tabs. I need to detect the page that add my app. I can just get the url bec. page ID was declared there but facebook put the app inside an iframe and I can't use any javascript or php script to get it.

Comment: Fist link found in Google.com http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=179394698802609

Comment: @OM I'm pretty sure he means programmatically; that can be done by decoding the `$_REQUEST['signed_request']` value, either directly http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ or using SDK jsut as @Sudhir below does

Answer (score 4):

If you can use PHP then, this would work:

```
<?php
// PATH TO FB-PHP-SDK
require '../../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if( $page = $signed_request['page'] ) {
    echo $page['id'];
}
?>
```

Did you mean something like that

Answer (score 1):

You can get the page id by doing a request like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/DomaineNameOfYourPage

Comment: That won't work if he doesn't have the page's username, which he won't because it's another page his app is installed on